# Hosts file change syntax

Tags: hosts

I am attempting to migrate a website to a ubuntu server but would like to test it first

On windows I have changed my host file to point to the server, so the browser is opening the "new" site. In my terminal , in Ubuntu I have changed the following

```
127.0.1.1 example example
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

to

```
127.0.1.1 example example
127.0.0.1 localhost
104.236.247.139 www.example.com
104.236.247.139 example.com


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Can I confirm that this is correct? I seem to be running into issues with finding http image urls etc, and before trying to debug I want to make the hosts file is correctly set.

Thanks

Comment: You should probably have `104.236.247.139 www.example.com example.com` (i.e., one entry per IP with multiple hostnames separated by space).

Comment: Please confirm, that your `/etc/hosts` doesn't contain Windows line endings (CR-LF). You can check with `file /etc/hosts` or `echo "I found $(tr -cd '\r' < /etc/hosts | wc -c) carriage return characters."`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `/etc/hosts` file should look like this:

```
127.0.1.1 example
127.0.0.1 localhost
104.236.247.139 www.example.com example.com


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

For `127.0.1.1` you have put two same hostnames whereas just one will do. For the IP `104.236.247.139` you have used two different lines to express hostname and alias but you should put the hostname and aliases all in a single line separated by whitespaces, for example:

```
<IP_Address> <hostname> <alias_1> <alias_2> <alias_3>
104.236.247.139 www.example.com example.com foo.com bar.com
```

Comment: just one other question, should i need to restart any service or anything like that for it to take effect? Thanks

Comment: No, the changes to `hosts` are applied immediately.